# Perl one liner to find and replace it on multiple lines

Tags: regex, perl

The file is like this

```
>>
>>-- @@@@EOC@@@@;
>>select * from t1030a1;

A1  B1          C1  D1     
--  ----------  --  -------

A   steven      C   walter 
D   melissa     C   7      
E   monica      Q   sue    
A   t1030a1     C   C++    
A   t1030a1     C   C++    

--- 5 row(s) selected.
>>
>>-- @@@@EOC@@@@;
>>log;
```

Expected output:

```
>>select * from t1030a1;

A1  B1          C1  D1     
--  ----------  --  -------

A   steven      C   walter 
D   melissa     C   7      
E   monica      Q   sue    
A   t1030a1     C   C++    
A   t1030a1     C   C++    

--- 5 row(s) selected.
>>log;
```

I have tried to display 2 lines `>>\n>>-- @@@@EOC@@@@;` But it doesn't work.

```
MXX:`perl -ne 'print if />>\n>>-- \@\@\@\@EOC\@\@\@\@\;/' a1log`
MXX:
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason your one-liner doesn't work is that it spans two lines, but you read the file one line at the time. So it can never match. You need to read the file as a single line to do that. However, why not do something like this:

```
perl -ne 'print unless /^>>(\s*|-- @@.*)$/'
```

I used `.*` to fill in the rest of the line, as it was needlessly specific for the limited sample data. If you need it that specific, you can use the regex you already had, it looked like it would work.

If you should want to try your own one-liner, you can add the switch `-0777` and see if it matches.

Answer (score 0):

Escaping the @ signs makes it work although I'm not quite sure why.

```
$ perl -ne 'print if ($_ !~ /^>>(-- \@\@\@\@EOC\@\@\@\@;)?\s*$/)' < test.log 
>>select * from t1030a1;

A1  B1          C1  D1     
--  ----------  --  -------

A   steven      C   walter 
D   melissa     C   7      
E   monica      Q   sue    
A   t1030a1     C   C++    
A   t1030a1     C   C++    

--- 5 row(s) selected.
>>log;
```

Comment: Escaping `@` works because otherwise `@EOC` is interpolated as an array. However, the other combinations, e.g. `@@` or `@;` would not be considered meta characters and do not need escaping in this case.